# How to connect to Local Ganache from Eth.Build

Tags: ganache

I am running Ganache on my local (laptop).
I want to be able to connect eth.build blockchain module to this local ganache

By default, it is not able to do so. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Enable "mixed content" on eth.build website. The steps are a bit different for each browser, but the idea is the same.

Ganache runs on `http` whereas `eth.build` runs on `https`, so by default it wont allow to connect to `http`.

To make it work, just enable eth.build to work with mixed content:

[image: allow mixed content]

Now, You should be able to connect it to local blockchain node (ganache)

[image: Able to check balance of address on local ganache from blockchain node in eth.build]